# GWT Lock/Freeze/Pin Rows

Tags: gwt

I'm looking to pin rows, in my case the first n rows (+ header row), so that when the table is scrolled those rows stay at the top.

```
Header 1 (pinned)
Row 1    <- pin at top
Row 2    <- pin at top
Row 3    <- scroll with rest of table
```

I know DataGrid let's you pin the header, but I want some rows as well. I thought I saw an example of this at some point, but can't find it. CellTable, DataGrid, or even the Visualization Table would be acceptable. At first I thought I might be able to make a Custom DataProvider, but that doesn't look like the right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a cross-browser solution, I think you have no other choice but make 2 CellTables: one for the header rows and "pinned rows", the other one in a ScrollPanel for the rest of the table.

This is basically what `DataGrid` does under-the-hood.

Of course, that means you'd have to use custom data providers: one for the pinned rows, one for the scrollable rows.